# STM32Cube IDE: Unable to open and build a folder as a project

Tags: stm32cubeide

I want to ask how to open a project in stm32cube IDE.

To be specific, I was given a project organized as the picture below. The name of the containing folder is Project_Comm.

[image]

While the main code is in Core folder, the linker file and the project file of STM32CubeIDE is in STM32CubeIDE folder. In this case, how can I open the project with the main code and the Linker file in the Project Explorer?

What I did so far were:

- I tried to open the project by the .project and .cproject file from the folder STM32CubeIDE. It only opened the main code in Core folder (the linker file was not there) and I could not build the project.
- I imported the project by File>Import>Import ac6 System Workbench for STM32 Project. Then I chose the directory containing all of the Folder in the picture above and there were 2 folders: Project_Comm, and Project_Comm./STM32CubeIDE. I chose both of them and , in other tries, each of them but nothing worked. When I chose only the Project_Comm, nothing was imported.

Thank you, Huy Nguyen.

Answer (score 1):

The example is in set of examples which can be downloaded from Example Selector of STM32CubeMX.
At first, it was in Visual Code(during which I did not know I could download example).